# How to compare TimeZones

Tags: java, timezone, comparison, comparator

I need to compare time zones such that `Asia/Singapore` < `UTC` < `Pacific/Honolulu`.

I'm working with [`java.util.TimeZone`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) (which doesn't implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)).

My search for an existing implementation was unsuccessful because of the overwhelming number of questions about comparing dates with different time zones.

**Question:** What is a correct implementation of `Comparator<TimeZone>` that will solve this problem (and what makes it better than other solutions, if applicable)?

Note that I'm not able to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for this problem, so "use Joda Time" is not a valid answer.

#### Edit for clarity

The `<` notation above was not well defined. My particular use case only requires a naive "geographical" ordering from east to west. As the comments have pointed out, a more advanced and generalizable solution would take into account temporal factors like daylight savings time and historical GMT offset changes. So I think there are two orderings we can consider, each requiring a different `Comparator<TimeZone>` implementation:

- Strictly geographical (current UTC) - addressed by [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169112/697449).
- Sensitive to local or civil time changes - addressed by [rgettman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15169483/697449).

Comment: What are the ordering rules for TimeZone?

Comment: @SteveKuo Updated the question for clarity on the ordering. Does my edit make sense to you? Let me know how I can improve the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One might be able to create a `Comparator<TimeZone>` that takes into account time zone differences.  The `TimeZone` may or may not obvserve daylight savings time, which would adjust the raw offset, thus messing up raw-offset-only comparisons.  The `TimeZone` class seems to support the adjustment based on the 2 `getOffset` methods, but they need a reference date.  How about:

```
public class TimeZoneComparator implements Comparator<TimeZone>
{
   private long date;

   public TimeZoneComparator(long date)
   {
      this.date = date;
   }

   public int compare(TimeZone tz1, TimeZone tz2)
   {
      return tz2.getOffset(this.date) - tz2.getOffset(this.date);
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice approach! See my edit for clarity in the question in case you're interested (and sorry it took a while).

Comment: The result will return equal when tz1 is DST and tz2 is not, (or the other way around).  But it will return equal for disparate timezones, under that circumstance.  Correct?  So, this is computationally correct but not "politcally" correct.  You do see why.  Is there a way to add a non-DST vs DST compensator?  Timezone is DST aware, I believe.  So, this is a way for a correction: TimeZone.getTimeZone( "US/Eastern").inDaylightTime( new Date() );

Answer (score 4):

I rolled my own `Comparator<TimeZone>` implementation using [`getRawOffset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getRawOffset%28%29) for the comparison:

```
@Override
public int compare(TimeZone tz1, TimeZone tz2) {
    return tz2.getRawOffset() - tz1.getRawOffset();
}
```

It seems to have passed a quick test:

```
final List<TimeZone> timeZones = Arrays.asList(
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Honolulu"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore")
);

final List<TimeZone> expectedOrder = Arrays.asList(
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"),
        TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Honolulu")
);

Collections.sort(timeZones, new Comparator<TimeZone>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(TimeZone tz1, TimeZone tz2) {
        return tz2.getRawOffset() - tz1.getRawOffset();
    }
});

//Impl note: see AbstractList.equals
System.out.println(timeZones.equals(expectedOrder)); //true
```

But I'm still wondering whether there are pitfalls to this solution and/or if there's something preferable.

Comment: What about daylight savings time?  Depending on the date, it may or may not be in effect, thus making the raw offset insufficient for comparison.

Comment: Is this meant to be definitive?  Definitive meaning all time zones. It is not, IMO.  Does raw_offset account for DST?  I do not know, but I think so.  Please verify. In some TZ settings, when DST comes and goes is not predictable.  Israeli DST for example.

Comment: @jim The value returned by `getRawOffset` is not affected by DST according to the javadoc.

Comment: Meaning your code is not doing what you want some times during the year.

Comment: @rgettman You both pose an excellent question. I think it watersheds into a greater question concerning the conceptual order of time zones. Given that my ordering does *not* observe DST, what could be the pitfalls of using it? Is it more correct to order based on time of year and why? Let me know if you think I should edit the question to clarify anything.

Comment: Your code will not work in Northern Arizona.  Period.  Look at a timezone map there.  I picked Arizona because it is someplace that is not a bizarre location to run an app.  There are other examples: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone.html?n=286&syear=2000 if you go into the past DST will come and go at different times.

Comment: A pitfall is that a comparison would yield different results depending on whether daylight savings time is in effect.  E.g. "America/Los_Angeles" is normally GMT-8, and "America/Phoenix" is normally GMT-7, clearly not equal.  But the former observes DST, becoming GMT-7, and the latter does not observe DST, making them equal.  Your comparator will need the "date of comparison", perhaps as a constructor argument, to make decisions based on whether daylight savings time is in effect on that date.

Comment: You're both making excellent points but I'm confused why you aren't submitting them as answers that will help other people ;)

Answer (score 1):

Timezones are purely political, so  any use of them that is non-conforming will cause LOTS of problems for users, depending on what the app does and who needs it or uses it.  You question would be better asked by explaining why you need them ordered like that.  There are adjacent timezones where one uses DST the other does not.  So 60% of the year, the TZ1 == TZ2, the other 40% TZ1 < TZ2.  Or whatever the case may be.

There are geographic (lat long) timezone data sets, and web sites to query for timezone.  Even current DST settings.  So you may have to settle for a data set that you need to update frequently at least yearly.  Or web access.

You probably should not assign magnitude to them.  Only geographic ordering - by longitude.

First of if you could tell us what you are trying to do it'd be great. And the answer is not:  strict a>b>c order based on local time.  I coded calendrics for a while, so I actually used to know this stuff.
What explictly do believe requires this kind of ordering?

Comment: So what would your `Comparator<TimeZone>` implementation be?

Comment: See my update for clarity to the question - lemme know how I can further improve it.

Comment: Please state what you are trying to accomplish that requires ordering of timezones.  See my edit above.

Comment: My use case was simply to list them geographically. My naive comparison was enough to solve this. But, I got interested in what is described in the second bullet point of my question after posting it, and encouraged you and others to post solutions that would help other people. As it is, your answer isn't very constructive, but you seem to have a lot of expertise and I have high hopes for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
java.util.TimeZone#hasSameRules
```

is made for this and exists already. It compares two TimeZones about their offsets and whether they are using daylightTime.

```
public boolean hasSameRules(TimeZone other) {
    return other != null && getRawOffset() == other.getRawOffset() &&
        useDaylightTime() == other.useDaylightTime();
}
```